# Angular 2 not showing output on screen

Tags: angularjs, angular

Since I have begin to learn Angular 2 , I am following the basic concepts well. But when I tried running the below program, I don't get the values which is statically set in the code.

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
hero: Hero = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Windstorm'
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
 template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2><div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div><div><label>name: </label>{{hero.name}}</div>'

})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero = 'Windstorm';
}
```

Can someone please point out where I am wrong, also can someone show how to debug the Angular code so that I can learn the framework well and try complex things out by self-learning and solve out basic issues by myself?

[The output which I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMlxx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
 template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1><h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2><div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div><div><label>name: </label>{{hero.name}}</div>'

})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

With `hero = 'Windowstorm';` `{{hero.name}}` is invalid because `hero` doesn't have a `name` property. 
I'm sure your browser console show an error message. Please add such errors to future questions.

Comment: I am sorry but the console didn't show up anything.Its clear.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It would only cause an error if `hero` had been `null`. It's still helpful to state if questions state whether the console did show errors or not ;-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity why would externalizing her class not give me out.Even if the change the hero key to some other name in AppComponent?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question. Bindings in templates can only refer to properties of the components class instance. `hero: Hero = { id: 1, ...}` is outside the class and out of reach for the template, thus `{{hero}}` binds to `hero = 'Windstorm';`.

Comment: Sure I get it. Will learn how to make it in scope by reading some more facts.Thanks for the answer..Cheers.